# Using sed I want to replace the first block of text that matches

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed

I have a script with hundreds of lines and while my search and replace command works and removes it in multiple locations.

The text to replace is located in another file and my search and replace works perfectly but unfortunately I want only the first instance of the block text to be replaced.

ORIGINAL_FILE
TEXT_FILE
NEW_FILE

Replace all text between RECOMMENDED and STATIC with content from TEXT_FILE

```
sed -n -e "1,/RECOMMENDED/ p" -e "/STATIC/,$ p" -e "/RECOMMENDED/ r $TEXT_FILE" $ORIGINAL_FILE >$NEW_FILE
```

As I say this works but there are multiple locations where RECOMMENDED and STATIC are available and I want to only change the first instance.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```
sed -n -e '1,/RECOMMENDED/ p' \
       -e '/STATIC/,$ {p;d;}' \
       -e "/RECOMMENDED/ r $TEXT_FILE" < "$ORIGINAL_FILE" > "$NEW_FILE"
```

Then the `/RECOMMENDED/` won't match after lines matching `/STATIC/` since we **d**elete them after printing.

Comment: Hello Stephane that kinda worked also but for some reason it added the content of the $TEXT_FILE 4 times in the $NEW_FILE and I believe it's because the RECOMMENDED .... STATIC exists in multiple locations in the $ORIGINAL_FILE file.

Comment: @gcclinux, with that code, that would only happen in there were several occurrences of _RECOMMENDED_ before the first _STATIC_

Comment: Hi Stéphane thank you for your advise and that may be the issue the script contains multiple blocks of code containing RECOMMENDED & STATIC and therefore I wish to only replace the 1st instance and ignore the subsequence ones, if you have any idea that would be great, i could provide code snips of the script if that helps or send you the entire script if you could help.

Comment: @gcclinux, please update your question to give a minimal sample input to work on. One for which this answer is currently not satisfactory. Clarifying if those blocks can be nested or not, etc.

Comment: @ Stéphane I've modified what I am searching for and the script update works as you described.
I take a snip from what I want to keep in the old script, replace the snip in to the new script as you described and it workers perfectly.. Thank you